# why there is no temperature and density in the formula of the electrical resistance?

Tags: temperature, electrical-resistance, density

Why there is no temperature and density in the formula of the electrical resistance?

We all know, that the electrical resistance depends on length, temperature, density( material).

Why is the measurement unit ohm $Ω = \frac{m^2kg}{s^3A^2}$ and not $\frac{m^2Kg}{Km^4}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because conventionally we assume constant temperature, and length and density are also assumed to be constants for a given resistor.

Of course, this is not true. In some circuit designs I have to pay very careful attention to resistance changes with temperature, and indeed this is sometimes used to provide temperature measurements in the form of [RTD](http://www.temperatures.com/rtds.html) devices. However, when it comes to resistors a lot of effort goes into eliminating such dependencies.

Changes in resistance with density and length are also far less important unless that effect is desired in, for example the rather interesting [Starling Resistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starling_resistor)

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I don't have yet enough reputation to upvote you.

Comment: Have a point or two!